# Why $\{x\in\ell^\infty \mid \|x\|_{\ell^\infty }\leq 1\}$ is not completely bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

We say that $\mathcal A$ is completely bounded if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there are $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $$\mathcal A\subset B(x_1,\varepsilon)\cup\cdots\cup B(x_n,\varepsilon).$$

Why $$S=\{x\in \ell^\infty \mid \|x\|_{\ell^\infty }\leq 1\}$$
is not completely bounded ? (where $\|x\|_{\ell^\infty }=\sup\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\ldots\}$). For me such a set looks completely bounded... (I'm not used to those functional spaces, so sorry if my question is very stupid)

Comment: Note $\{e_n: n=1, 2, \cdots\}$ are in $\ell^\infty$ and $\|e_n - e_m\|_\infty = 1$ if $m\neq n$.

Comment: "We say that $\mathcal A$ is completely bounded if..." actually we don't say that, we say it's _totally bounded_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
& (0,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
& (0,0,1,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
& (0,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots) \\
& \qquad \vdots
\end{align}
The distance between any two of these is $1.$ Therfore the neighborhood of radius $\varepsilon=1/2$ about any of them excludes all of the others. Hence such neighborhoods about finitely many of them exclude all of the others. You cannot cover the whole space with finitely many of those balls.

Comment: In fact, if you make a sequence corresponding to each subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then all of those are at distance 1 from each other, so $\ell^\infty$ can't even be covered by countably many balls of radius $1/2$.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. I wouldn't think about that (infinite dimension is so complicated... my brain has problem to imagine such things... you must be so brilliant !) Thanks you very very much :) btw should the radius must be strictly smaller that 1/2 ? because with a radius of 1/2 it can contain an other element, no ?

Comment: @Henri : The distance between $(1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(0,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ is $1,$ so neither of those is within the neighborhood of radius $1/2$ about the other.